# Google Maps API V3 - Custom infobox for multiple polygons

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, polygons

This is my first time working with the Google Maps API. I have a styled map with multiple polygons that each need their own infobox.  The infoboxes need to be styled.  My problem is that I can't get the infoboxes to work at all.  I've been looking for a solution for days now, I've even tried this http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/examples/infobox-basic.html I must obviously be doing something wrong.

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/M23PPXpn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that attaching an Infobox to a polygon results in this error in infobox.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<V> has no method 'getPosition'
```

It could be because a polygon represents an area, while a marker represents a point. I suggest creating a single invisible marker somewhere inside your polygons to anchor each infobox.

With this idea, I added a infobox to the Australia polygon. The click listener is still created for the polygon, but it opens the infobox tied to the invisible marker.

```
// ... this is near the end of your code...

australia_new_zealand.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(australia_new_zealand, 'mouseover', function() {
    this.setOptions({fillColor: "#28d1e9"}); 
});
google.maps.event.addListener(australia_new_zealand, 'mouseout',function(){
 this.setOptions({fillColor: "#06376a"});   
});

      // marker inside the Australia polygon, LatLng was manually defined
      var australia_new_zealand_center = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-24.5271348225978, 134.296875),
        visible: false
      });

      var boxText = document.createElement("div");
      boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
      boxText.innerHTML = "City Hall, Sechelt<br>British Columbia<br>Canada";

      var myOptions = {       
        content: boxText,
        maxWidth: 0,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
        zIndex: null,
        boxStyle: {  background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat", opacity: 0.75, width: "280px" } ,
        closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
        closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
        isHidden: false,
        pane: "floatPane",
        enableEventPropagation: false
      }

      // listener responds to a click inside polygon
      google.maps.event.addListener(australia_new_zealand, "click", function (e) {
        ib.open(map, australia_new_zealand_center);
      });

      var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);

//(end) REGION - AUSTRALIA NEW ZEALAND
}
```

Comment: excellent, thank you! I used an infoBubble instead but your suggestion for the invisible marker worked great!

Comment: You are my hero!! I was searching for a solution like this for weeks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this playground with examples [Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#info_windows_complex_v3)